# Best method for logging activity (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging

I want to log the user activity through my Rails 2.3.8 application.  I don't care what the activity is, just the last time any given user did *anything* on the site, including viewing pages, commenting, logging in, etc.

One method that I can think of is creating at last_active DateTime attribute in the user model and constantly updating this attribute based on a user's activity (or possibly taking advantage of the updated_at column).  I could put an after_filter on every action of every controller to call an update method, but this seems hacky and excessive.  There must be a better way.  Would an observer work? If so - how? Is there something built-in to Rails that I'm missing here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Put your `after_filter` on the `ApplicationController`. You can turn it off in other controllers with `skip_after_filter` as needed.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to have worked!  Any potential performance issues with this?