# How to log searches in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, solr, sunspot

I'd like to keep a log of all searches that users do on my site which uses the sunspot-rails gem. I don't need the logs to be real-time accessible by my application as they're for analytics that will be processed later.

I'm thinking that I should do the logging in rails rather than in solr itself so that I have access to the entire session, but I'm not sure how to build that.  Is there a standard method for this? I saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5669871/best-method-for-logging-activity-ruby-on-rails) but I would think there would be something more generic than writing it all myself in ApplicationController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ultimate answer depends on howwhere you're implementing your search. If you have a single search controller, do the logging there. If you have a collection of search controllers, either do it in each one, or create a base class, do the filter/logging in the base class.

Can you provide any more details?

Comment: I am using a single search controller, but I'm just hoping for some standard best practices here. Should I log the searches to the database? Should I put them in a file first and then have a delayed job load them in? What gothca's are there that people have hit before, that kind of thing. Thanks!

Comment: Oh. It totally depends--I don't think there's any best way. Analytics can be pulled either from a DB or a log. If you're looking for ad hoc, real-time analytics, the DB is probably a better choice. If you have the time to process a log file, it may be slightly less resource-intensive during normal operation--the trade-off comes in the batch processing.

Comment: Ok, I think I'll end up rolling my own in my search controller, like you suggested.